# ReactJS + Material-UI: How to use Material-UI’s FlatButton and Dialog in each TableRow?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I have a Material-UI’s `<Table>`, and in each `<TableRow>` (which is dynamically rendered) for the `<TableBody>`, I would like to have a button (`<FlatButton>`) for one of the columns. And once the button is clicked on, it will open up a `<Dialog>` and inside it would like to have a working `<Tabs>`.

So how can I display a `<FlatButton>` for each row for a particular column, and when the button is clicked on, display the `<Dialog>` along with a working `<Tabs>` on the inside as the content? And have the `<Dialog>` close when clicked on outside?

So far I have the following, but came across the following issues: the  opens up but it is slow and clicking outside the `<Dialog>` is not closing it, the `<Tabs>` is visible but it is not working:

Main Table:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  Subheader,
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableHeader,
  TableHeaderColumn,
  TableRow,
} from 'material-ui'

import RenderedTableRow from ‘./RenderedTableRow'

export default class MainTable extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
        <Subheader>Table</Subheader>
          <Table
            multiSelectable={true}
          >
            <TableHeader
              displaySelectAll={true}
              enableSelectAll={true}
            >
              <TableRow>
                <TableHeaderColumn>
                  Col 1
                </TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn>
                  Col 2
                </TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn>
                  Col 3
                </TableHeaderColumn>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHeader>
            <TableBody
              deselectOnClickaway={false}
              stripedRows
           >
              <RenderedTableRow {...this.props}/>
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Rendered Table Row:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { Dialog, FlatButton, Tabs, Tab,  TableRow, TableRowColumn } from 'material-ui'
import ContentAdd from 'material-ui/svg-icons/content/add';

export default class RenderedTableRow extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      open: false,
    }

    this._handleOpen = this._handleOpen.bind(this)
    this._handleClose = this._handleClose.bind(this)
  }

  _handleOpen() {
    this.setState({
      open: true
    })
  }

  _handleClose() {
    this.setState({
      open: false
    })
  }

  render() {
    const {
      children,
      ...rest
    } = this.props

    const actions = [
      <FlatButton
        label="Cancel"
        primary={true}
        onClick={this._handleClose}
      />,
    ]

    return (
      <TableRow {...rest}>
        {children[0]}
        <TableRowColumn>Red</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>John, Joshua</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>
          <FlatButton
            icon={<ContentAdd/>}
            onClick={this._handleOpen}
          />
        </TableRowColumn>

        <Dialog
          actions={actions}
          autoScrollBodyContent={true}
          open={this.state.open}
          onRequestClose={this._handleClose}
          modal={false}
          title='Test'
        >
            <Tabs>
              <Tab label="Item One" >
                <div>
                  <h2 >Tab One</h2>
                  <p>
                    This is an example tab.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </Tab>

              <Tab label="Item Two" >
                <div>
                  <h2>Tab Two</h2>
                  <p>
                    This is another example tab.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </Tab>

            </Tabs>
        </Dialog>
      </TableRow>
    )
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance and will accept/upvote answer.

Comment: What will be displayed in the dialog? For each row you're generating a new Dialog - is it necessary? As you mentioned, it will be very slow. Better approach is to have one Dialog element in the main table component and pass the necessary props.

Comment: I'd move the dialog outside of the table, pass a callback to a button in the table row that on click, opens dialog and pass the selected row to it

Comment: @szymonm Different content for each row, but it will be displayed by using `<Tabs>` inside the Dialog but currently the Tabs don't work. The reason why I did it for each row is because each dialog is represented differently for every row. How can I get around that?

Comment: @Mateusz Do you mind showing as answer for clarification? So I can accept and upvote it as well.

Comment: @philippspo updated his answer and it's exactly what you need there ;-)

Comment: @szymonm Still don't seem to work :( Help?

Comment: @Mateusz Still no luck. Help please?

Comment: Could you please edit your question or maybe create a codepen with your not-working solution? That way we would be able to see what's wrong there...

Comment: @JoKo did you see my answer below? did it help?

Answer (score 2):

You should probably only have one dialog for the whole table that lives in your `MainTable` component. This is more efficient because you don't need a dialog per row but only one dialog.

In order for the button in the `RenderedTableRow` to open the modal and tell it which row is selected you need to pass down a callback function from `MainTable` to `RenderedTableRow` that when called, sets the dialog to be opened and stores which row was selected:

```
export default class MainTable extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedRow: null,
  }
  handleSelectRow(rowIndex) {
    this.setState({
      selectedRow: rowIndex,
    })
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Subheader>Table</Subheader>
          <Table
            multiSelectable={true}
          >
            // ...
            <TableBody
              deselectOnClickaway={false}
              stripedRows
              >
              {rows.map((row, index) => (
                <RenderedTableRow
                  row={row}
                  {...this.props}
                  onSelectRow={() => this.handleSelectRow(index)}
                  />
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </div>
        // Dialog goes here and is only rendered once per table
        // it is only open when there is a row selected
        <Dialog
          open={Boolean(this.state.selectedRow)}
        >
          // you can get the selected row with rows[this.state.selectedRow]
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: For there to be dynamic multiple rows, I'll be populating the table with an array with specific properties for each row like so: `<TableBody>{array.map(row => {return(<RenderedTableRow/>)})};</TableBody>`. If that's the case, how would I differentiate which row has been clicked on and display that specific content inside a dialog for that particular row clicked on? Because each row will display different content inside a dialog. Also why don't the `<Tabs>` work?

Comment: I extended the code sample to include multiple rows. Not sure why the `Tabs` would not work though. They look fine to me. I even tried your `Dialog` code out and the `Tabs` work for me.

Comment: do you mind showing it with codepen or anything similar? Don't seem to be working.. :(

Comment: Just checking in to see if you've seen my previous comment. Please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example below, it should work straight via copy pasta.

The answer to your question is that you need to be able to differentiate between the different `rows`, setting it to `true` will display all dialogs, or possibly just the last.  Once you differentiate it, displaying the `dialog` you want shouldn't be a problem.  There are ways to just have one `dialog` and still have this work, but I'll let you figure it out.

Somethings to note, is that you can definitely clean this code up.  Create separate files for creating `TableRows` `TableColumns` etc.

I left it at two columns for now, however you should be able to understand the code.  Feel free to ask any additional questions.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { Dialog, FlatButton, Tabs, Tab,  TableRow, TableRowColumn } from 'material-ui'
import ContentAdd from 'material-ui/svg-icons/content/add';

class MainTable extends Component {
  static fields = [{tab1:"a", tab2:"b"}, {tab1:"c", tab2:"d"}];

  state = {
    open: false,
  }

  handleOpen = (field) => () => {
    this.setState({
      open: field
    })
  }

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({
      open: false
    })
  }

  renderRows = (field) => {
    const { open } = this.state;

    const actions = [
      <FlatButton
        label="Cancel"
        primary={true}
        onTouchTap={this.handleClose}
      />,
      <FlatButton
        label="Submit"
        primary={true}
        keyboardFocused={true}
        onTouchTap={this.handleClose}
      />,
    ];

    return (<TableRow key={field.tab1}>
      <TableRowColumn>{field.tab1}</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>
        <FlatButton
        icon={<ContentAdd/>}
        onClick={this.handleOpen(field.tab1)}
      />
      </TableRowColumn>
        <Dialog
          title="Dialog With Actions"
          actions={actions}
          modal={false}
          open={open === field.tab1}
          onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
        >
        <Tabs>
          <Tab label={field.tab1} >
            <div>
              <h2>{field.tab1}</h2>
              <p>
                This is one tab.
              </p>
            </div>
          </Tab>

          <Tab label={field.tab2}>
            <div>
              <h2>{field.tab2}</h2>
              <p>
                This is another example tab.
              </p>
            </div>
          </Tab>
        </Tabs>
      </Dialog>
    </TableRow>);
  }

  render() {
    const rows = MainTable.fields.map(this.renderRows);
    return (
      <div>
        {rows}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default MainTable;
```

Comment: For there to be dynamic multiple rows, I'll be populating the table with an array with specific properties for each row like so: <TableBody>{array.map(row => {return(<RenderedTableRow/>)})};</TableBody>. If that's the case, how would I differentiate which row has been clicked on and display that specific content inside a dialog for that particular row clicked on? Because each row will display different content inside a dialog. Also why don't the <Tabs> work? If you can show actually working one, that'd would really help.

Comment: I'm at work now, but I'll update the answer later tonight to show working `tabs`.  I left that part out.

Comment: Btw, did you try the code out above?  Clicking on the different `rows` displays the different types of data.  The only thing I didn't look into are `tabs`, I'm not sure what they do, but I can check the docs later.

Comment: Here you go @JoKo.  It is a complete working example with tabs.  I hope it helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned earlier in the comments, you should have only one `Dialog` element along with the table component. Embedding `Dialog` in each row will impact the performance and is general a bad practice. Here is the solution for mocked tabs:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { find } from 'lodash';
import { Dialog, FlatButton, Tabs, Tab, TableRow, TableRowColumn } from 'material-ui';
import ContentAdd from 'material-ui/svg-icons/content/add';

class MainTable extends Component {
  // mocked data to show you the example:
  static fields = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'John',
    tabs: [{
      header: 'Tab 1 John',
      content: 'Content of tab 1 for John'
    }, {
      header: 'Tab 2 John',
      content: 'Content of tab 2 for John'
    }]
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'George',
    tabs: [{
      header: 'Tab 1 George',
      content: 'Content of tab 1 for George'
    }, {
      header: 'Tab 2 George',
      content: 'Content of tab 2 for George'
    }]
  }];

  state = {
    activeRowId: null  // we will store the `id` of the active row (opened dialog)
  };

  handleOpen = (rowId) => () => {
    this.setState({
      activeRowId: rowId  // set `id` taken from the row
    });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({
      activeRowId: null  // reset active `id`
    });
  };

  renderRows = (field) => (
    <TableRow key={`row-${field.id}`}>
      <TableRowColumn>{field.name}</TableRowColumn>
      <TableRowColumn>
        <FlatButton
          icon={<ContentAdd />}
          onClick={this.handleOpen(field.id)}
        />
      </TableRowColumn>
    </TableRow>
  );

  render() {
    const rows = MainTable.fields.map(this.renderRows);
    const { activeRowId } = this.state;
    const actions = [
      <FlatButton
        label="Cancel"
        primary
        onTouchTap={this.handleClose}
      />,
      <FlatButton
        label="Submit"
        primary
        keyboardFocused
        onTouchTap={this.handleClose}
      />,
    ];
    const activeRow = find(MainTable.fields, { id: activeRowId }); // find the data for this active row `id`
    return (
      <div>
        {rows}
        {activeRow ? (
          <Dialog
            title="Dialog title"
            actions={actions}
            modal={false}
            open
            onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
          >
            <Tabs>
              {activeRow.tabs.map((tab, index) => (
                <Tab label={tab.header} key={`tab-${index}`}>
                  <div>
                    <h2>{tab.header}</h2>
                    <p>{tab.content}</p>
                  </div>
                </Tab>
              ))}
            </Tabs>
          </Dialog>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MainTable;
```

**This is how it works right now:**

[image]

**Few remarks:**

- you should split this code into smaller components, I wrote this all in one to make it easy to test it,
- remember to use `key` prop in all the elements of the list (where you iterate over a list) - both rows and tabs (`key` is missing in your question).